# Meteorjs, how to set MONGO_OPLOG_URL to use localhost's MongoDB replication directly?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

My service is running on one server with Metoer project and MongoDB,
and there's one another replication server for MongoDB.

So I've configured Mongo replication with two official IP, and configured two MONGO_OPLOG_URL with the same two official IP when running Meteor project.

The question is, in this case, 
when Meteor project fetch some data, does it use the network to get the data from the local MongoDB?
Because I didn't setup any hostname setting for its own official IP on my machine, so I doubt it may occur some data traffic to outside.

If I am right, how to config to use the Meteor server its localhost MongoDB without network traffic,
or if I am wrong, how does it work to use localhost db inside of the server if I use official IP for replication setting and meteor running environment?

Thanks in advance.